# Transform data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, transpose

[image]
I need some advice about which package command I can use in R to get from df to df2:

data frame called df where:
ex this is the head of df:

```
GeneIndex   SampleIndex tpm GeneID  GeneName
<int>   <int>   <dbl>   <chr>   <chr>
1   0   3893    3.231526e-01    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
2   0   14906   0.000000e+00    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
3   0   7474    0.000000e+00    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
4   0   1220    3.824092e-29    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
5   0   15831   0.000000e+00    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
6   0   5471    1.445461e-01    ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
.        ...     ...      ..                ..                  ..
```

To this where it looks more like a gene matrix as an example:
Where the SampleIndex is now transposed, the tpm values are maintained for each sample index and geneid; and the rows are GeneID
df2

```
GeneID                3893        14906       7474        1220          15831       5471 
ENSG00000223972.5  3.231526e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 3.824092e-29 0.000000e+00 1.445461e-01
```

not successful yet ...

Answer (score 1):

One option is using [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) function from the [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package:

```
df |> tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = GeneID, names_from = SampleIndex, values_from = tpm)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  GeneID            `8288` `5632` `7518` `5343` `2221` `3857`
  <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ENSG00000223972.5   45.9   33.2   65.1   25.8   47.9   76.6
```

Another alternative using base R is using [`xtabs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/xtabs):

```
xtabs(tpm ~ GeneID + SampleIndex, data = df)
```

Data:

```
set.seed(0)

df <- tibble(
  GeneIndex = 0,
  SampleIndex = sample(1000:10000, 6),
  tpm = runif(6, 0, 100),
  GeneID = "ENSG00000223972.5",
  GeneName = "DDX11L1")
```

Notes:

- It's probably not the greatest idea to give your columns numbers as names, just a heads up. It means when you want to reference them, you have to have backticks around each reference (e.g. `8288`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in base R as well:

```
dfl <- reshape(df[,2:4], direction = "wide", idvar = "GeneID", timevar = "SampleIndex")
names(dfl) <- gsub(pattern = "tpm.", replacement = "" , x=names(dfl))
```

This will return:

```
dfl
             GeneID      3893  14906  7474         1220  15831      5471
1 ENSG00000223972.5 0.3231526      0     0 3.824092e-29      0 0.1445461
```

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(GeneIndex = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SampleIndex = c(3893L, 
14906L, 7474L, 1220L, 15831L, 5471L), tpm = c(0.3231526, 0, 0, 
3.824092e-29, 0, 0.1445461), GeneID = c("ENSG00000223972.5", 
"ENSG00000223972.5", "ENSG00000223972.5", "ENSG00000223972.5", 
"ENSG00000223972.5", "ENSG00000223972.5"), GeneName = c("DDX11L1", 
"DDX11L1", "DDX11L1", "DDX11L1", "DDX11L1", "DDX11L1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```